# How to match string elements from one list with another list using regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have created a list which has day no. and the respective timing an employee has logged in. I want to find out on which days the employee has not logged any timings denoting he/she has taken a holiday.

```
pattern = ["Timings: "]
timingData = ['Day: 1.0 Timings: 09:52 17:46 ', 'Day: 2.0 Timings: 09:29 09:29 17:54 ', 'Day: 3.0 Timings: 09:28 09:28 17:42 ', 'Day: 4.0 Timings: 11:18 17:47 ', 'Day: 5.0 Timings: ', 'Day 6.0 Timings: ']
```

Using regex I want to find which Timings do not have digits after them and update the counter or log the position accordingly to count the number of holidays.

So Day: 5.0 and Day: 6.0 should be logged as holidays.

I tried online regex which worked. But I just can't figure out how do I implement it on my local editor.
[Link](https://regex101.com/r/ByaAXP/1/)

Comment: Would love to see what you've tried first ;-)

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: [I tried this](https://regex101.com/r/ByaAXP/1/) but I don't know how do I implement it in editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your posted string, you have word `Timings:` but your regex only contains `Timing:` which obviously won't match and looks like its a typo from your end.

You can use a simple regex, where if `Timings:` is followed by an optional space and at least two digits, then you can consider that timing data is present else not.

Here is a python code for same,

```
import re

timingData = ['Day: 1.0 Timings: 09:52 17:46 ', 'Day: 2.0 Timings: 09:29 09:29 17:54 ', 'Day: 3.0 Timings: 09:28 09:28 17:42 ', 'Day: 4.0 Timings: 11:18 17:47 ', 'Day: 5.0 Timings: ', 'Day 6.0 Timings: ']

for s in timingData:
 if (re.match(r'.*Timings:\s*\d{2}:.*', s)):
  print (s + ' --> ' + "Matched")
 else:
  print (s + ' --> ' + "Didn't match")
```

Which gives following output like you must expect,

```
Day: 1.0 Timings: 09:52 17:46  --> Matched
Day: 2.0 Timings: 09:29 09:29 17:54  --> Matched
Day: 3.0 Timings: 09:28 09:28 17:42  --> Matched
Day: 4.0 Timings: 11:18 17:47  --> Matched
Day: 5.0 Timings:  --> Didn't match
Day 6.0 Timings:  --> Didn't match
```

Comment: yeah it is typing error from my end. I'll update it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need regular expressions here. What if you would just *split on "Timings:"* and check what you've got in the result of a split. Looks clean to me:

```
In [1]: timingData = ['Day: 1.0 Timings: 09:52 17:46 ', 'Day: 2.0 Timings: 09:29 09:29 17:54 ', 'Day: 3.0 Timings: 09:28 09:28 17:42 ', 'Day: 4.0 Timings: 11:18 17:47 ', 'Day: 5.0 Timings: ', 'Day 6.0 Timings: ']

In [2]: for item in timingData:
            day, timing = item.split("Timings: ")
            if not timing:
                print(day)        
Day: 5.0 
Day 6.0
```

There is, of course, this assumption here that the items in the list follow this specific pattern.

Comment: So it splits the elements if there is a space after timings right? And if it cannot split then the respected day is printed right?

Comment: @NeerajLagwankar yeah, basically, if there is nothing after `Timings: `, we print out the day.

Comment: This is a pretty neat solution

Comment: @silverhash yeah, I've got my regex gold badge providing non-regex answers to regex questions :D

Comment: I really wanted to accept this as an answer but I couldn't since the ques was for regex. Thanks for this neat solution though. @alecxe

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by @alecxe, regex in this problem is overkill but If you really need to, I guess you could simply do something like:

```
import re
holidays = []

timingData = ['Day: 1.0 Timings: 09:52 17:46 ', 'Day: 2.0 Timings: 09:29 09:29 17:54 ', 'Day: 3.0 Timings: 09:28 09:28 17:42 ', 'Day: 4.0 Timings: 11:18 17:47 ', 'Day: 5.0 Timings: ', 'Day 6.0 Timings: ']

for t in timingData:
    a = re.search('(Timings:\s)[\w:\s]+',t)
    if a == None: #No matches found
            holidays.append(t[:8])
print(holidays)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
timingData = ['Day: 1.0 Timings: 09:52 17:46 ', 'Day: 2.0 Timings: 09:29 09:29 17:54 ', 'Day: 3.0 Timings: 09:28 09:28 17:42 ', 'Day: 4.0 Timings: 11:18 17:47 ', 'Day: 5.0 Timings: ', 'Day 6.0 Timings: ']

regexedData = []
for i in timingData:
    regexedData.append(re.findall(r'(.+?)(Timings:\s)$',i))
for i in regexedData:
    if i:
        print(i[0][0])
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
Day: 5.0
Day 6.0
```